# Game Center match is invalid always

Tags: swift, xcode, game-center

I'm trying to learn how to build a Game-Center based app. its a turn based extremely simple game that just basically logs what button you press and sends it to he other player. I am having a very hard time implementing all the game center features since Apple's documentation has not been updated for Swift. I've been guessing at everything and reading off Objective-C examples and hoping for the best (somehow I've managed to get a few things going, altough I'm not sure if they are correct)
Anyways, I made a new iCloud account for my Simulator and ran the app on my phone and the simulator simultaneously, trying to get them to match up in a game. However I always get a "match request is invalid" error:

**EDIT** I have registered the app in iTunesConnect, I've implemented leaderboards and tested them and they work (So I assume the iTunesConnect thing is properly working and set-up)

```
@IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.maxPlayers = 2
    request.minPlayers = 1

    let mmvc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    mmvc?.matchmakerDelegate = self
    present(mmvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension HomeVC: GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
{

    func authenticatePlayer()
    {
        //CALLED ON VIEWDIDAPPEAR
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view, error) in
            if view != nil
            {
                self.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("AUTHENTICATED!")
                print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here's the matchmaking code. Note I can get the Game Center screen to appear and tell me "how many players" and that its missing a player and gives the choice to invite friends and all that

```
extension HomeVC: GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate {
    func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
       print("match was cancelled")
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("didFailwithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {

        print("Match found, ID: \(match.description)")
        let gameScreenVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainGame") as! ViewController
        gameScreenVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        gameScreenVC.definesPresentationContext = true
        gameScreenVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        gameScreenVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        match.delegate = gameScreenVC

        self.present(gameScreenVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having this issue I fixed it by just replacing the "minelayers and max-layers" with the same amount, so the code now looks like this:

```
@IBAction func startTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.maxPlayers = 2 //min and max should be the same
    request.minPlayers = 2 //apparently they need to be the same

    let mmvc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    mmvc?.matchmakerDelegate = self
    present(mmvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

apparently Game Center does not like a min.player count of 1, its invalid. but thats how I got it to stop giving me Invalid Match Request warnings